# Use custom IServiceProvider implementation in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have implemented an adapter that implement `IServiceProvider` and returned it from the `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup.` class:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();

    var container = new NinjectComponentContainer(kernel);

    // ...

    return ServiceProviderFactory.Create(container, services);
}
```

However, my implementation doesn't seem to be used everywhere.  I even tried to override the `IHttpContextAccessor` to return a modified `HttpContext`:

```
    public HttpContext HttpContext {
        get
        {
            var result = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

            result.RequestServices = _serviceProvider;

            return result;
        }
        set => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext = value;
    }
```

To test whether I could get to my implementation I used a filter in order to see what the `HttpContext.RequestServices` would return:

```
public class AuthorizationTestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var service = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IAccessConfiguration));
    }
}
```

The type returned by `context.HttpContext.RequestServices` is:

[image]

My main issue was trying to get registered components resolved in the constructor *of a filter* but it always seems to fail saying the component is not registered.  However it *does* seem to work when using the `TypeFilter` attribute:

[TypeFilter(typeof(RequiresSessionAttribute))]

However, my attribute *does* inherit from `TypeFilter`:

```
public class RequiresSessionAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public RequiresSessionAttribute() : base(typeof(RequiresSession))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { };
    }

    private class RequiresSession : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly IAccessConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IDatabaseContextFactory _databaseContextFactory;
        private readonly ISessionQuery _sessionQuery;

        public RequiresSession(IAccessConfiguration configuration,
            IDatabaseContextFactory databaseContextFactory, ISessionQuery sessionQuery)
        {
            Guard.AgainstNull(configuration, nameof(configuration));
            Guard.AgainstNull(databaseContextFactory, nameof(databaseContextFactory));
            Guard.AgainstNull(sessionQuery, nameof(sessionQuery));

            _configuration = configuration;
            _databaseContextFactory = databaseContextFactory;
            _sessionQuery = sessionQuery;
        }
```

I did come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369555/custom-iservicepovider-is-not-always-used)  question but there is no definitive answer.

Any ideas on how to correctly provider a custom implementation of the `IServiceProvider` interface that will be used throughout the solution?

Comment: You should not try to replace the built-in container with Ninject, but rather run them side-by-side. You will run into all sorts of unsolvable problems, because Ninject behaves rather different from the given DI Abstraction. For more information, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32797105/264697).

Comment: @Steven: well, I'm not specifically using Ninject but rather an abstraction of my own.  I don't want to register the same types into multiple containers.  My idea is to use an adapter through `IServiceProvider` that would attempt to *first* resolve using the built-in container and then, as a fallback, my `IComponentContainer` implementation which could be any DI container.  But if you're saying that I should use the built-in container as a "real" container then I can create and adapter specifically for that. Just thought that the built-in container wasn't "production-grade".

Comment: @Steven: it really feels as though the previous versions of .net proper handled this in an easier way...

Comment: _"I don't want to register the same types into multiple containers"_ You shouldn't. You should register types in either one of them, not both. _" first resolve using the built-in container and then, as a fallback"_ I have never seen a reason for doing this. Could it be you are abusing the [Service Locator (anti-)pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)?

Comment: _"if you're saying that I should use the built-in container as a "real" container"_ Not exactly. You _could_ use the built-in container as application container, but my typical advise is to use the built-in container _only_ for handling framework stuff, and use a different container, you _application_ container, to resolve application components.

Comment: _"Just thought that the built-in container wasn't 'production-grade'"_ That depends on your definition of "production-grade". It is a stable library, bt is by design very limited in features, and you don't have to expect new features soon, because every change and new feature is a breaking change, since every change ripples through all the adapter implementations.

Comment: OK, so then wire up controllers and filters using a custom DI container and *not* the built-in one.  Is there any nice documentation on how to do that that you are aware of?  From what I've read it appeared as though the .net core team suggested using one of the established DI containers instead of the built-in one, but I could be wrong.  And no, I'm not abusing the service locator pattern :) --- I avoid it as far as possible.  I can see how you may think that given my example but that was only to check the type returned by the `RequestServices` property.

Comment: How to do this depends on your DI Container of choice. With Autofac, for instance, [the advice](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start-with-configurecontainer) is to use an adapter. With Simple Injector, on the other hand, you [keep both worlds separated](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore). But note that at some point, you will have to [cross-wire](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore#cross-wiring) 'some' services. There is more general documentation about the problems with ASP.NET Core [here](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/06/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though Microsoft states that it is possible to [replace the built-in container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-service-container-replacement) it appears as though it is not quite this simple, or even possible.

As stated by [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) in his very first comment, if you choose to use your container of choice, you should run them side-by-side.

The guidance from Microsoft suggests changing the `ConfigureServices` in the `Startup` class from this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // registrations into services
}
```

to the following:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var container = new YourContainer(); // Castle, Ninject, etc.

    // registrations into container

    return new YourContainerAdapter(container);
}
```

However, there are a number of issues with this since there are already framework registrations in `services` that we do not necessarily know how to re-register in our own container.  Well, there is a descriptor so if our container supports all the various methods then it is actually possible to re-register all the components.  The various DI containers have different mechanisms when it comes to registration and service resolution.  Some of them have a very hard distinction between the two making it quite tricky at times to accommodate a "common" solution.

My initial idea was to provide an adapter that accepts *both* my own container as well as the `services` collection from which I would then get the built-in service provider by calling `services.BuildServiceProvider()`.  In this way I could attempt to resolve from the built-in provider and then, if the resolving bit failed, attempt to resolve from my own container.  However, it turns out that the .net core implementation does in fact *not* use the returned `IServiceProvder` instance.

The only way I could get this to work was to wire up my own container and use it to resolve my controllers.  That could be done by providing an implementation of the `IControllerActivator` interface.

In this particular implementation I was fiddling with Ninject although I typically prefer Castle but the same applies to any DI container:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IKernel>(new StandardKernel());
    services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator, ControllerActivator>();
}

public class ControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public ControllerActivator(IKernel kernel)
    {
        Guard.AgainstNull(kernel, nameof(kernel));

        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public object Create(ControllerContext context)
    {
        return _kernel.Get(context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.AsType());
    }

    public void Release(ControllerContext context, object controller)
    {
        _kernel.Release(controller);
    }
}
```

In order to register the controller types I did my DI wiring in the `Configure` method since I have access to the `IApplicationBuilder` which can be used to get to the controller types:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    var kernel = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IKernel>();

    // kernel registrations

    var applicationPartManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationPartManager>();
    var controllerFeature = new ControllerFeature();

    applicationPartManager.PopulateFeature(controllerFeature);

    foreach (var type in controllerFeature.Controllers.Select(t => t.AsType()))
    {
        kernel.Bind(type).ToSelf().InTransientScope();
    }

    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors(
        options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
    );

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

This worked swimmingly for the controllers but resolving "filters" was still a problem given that they use the `IFilterFactory` on the filter itself to implement a factory method:

```
public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance (IServiceProvider serviceProvider);
```

Here we can see that the `IServiceProvider` implementation is provided in order to resolve any depedencies.  This applies when using the `TypeFilterAttribute` or when defining new filters that inherit from `TypeFilterAttribute` as I have in my question.

This mechanism is actually a very good example of the difference between "Inversion of Control" and "Dependency Injection".  The control lies with the framework (inversion) and we have to provide the relevant implementations.  The only issue here is that we are *not* able to hook in properly since our provided `IServiceProvider` instance is *not* passed to the `CreateInstance` method which then results in a failure when attempting to create an instance of the filter.  There are going to be a number of ways to fix this design but we'll leave that to Microsoft.

In order to get my filters working I decided to go the "cross-wiring" route as alluded to by Steven by simply registering the depedencies required by my filters in the `services` collection also:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IKernel>(new StandardKernel());
    services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator, ControllerActivator>();

    services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseContextFactory, DatabaseContextFactory>();
    services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseGateway, DatabaseGateway>();
    services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseContextCache, ContextDatabaseContextCache>();
    // and so on
}
```

Since I do not have many dependencies in my filter it works out OK.  This *does* mean that we have "duplicate" registrations that we need to be careful of depending on how the instances are used.

I guess another option may be to forego your DI container of choice and use only the built-in container.